# Free lightweight bbcode editor with jquery

Tags: jquery, bbcode

I want a BBCode editor that is/has:

- Free
- Lightweight
- Easily and cleanly install (not so much dependencies)
- Secure
- Able to be appended to the page later with jQuery
- List item
- Fast

Answer (score 3):

I found this http://sceditor.samclarke.com/
Really light weight and I am using it on my project :)

Answer (score 2):

Some more to the collection:

- http://www.wysibb.com/
- https://code.google.com/p/jquery-bbedit/
- https://github.com/Keloran/jQuery-BBCode-Editor
- https://github.com/kaimallea/jquery-bbcode

Comment: It looks like wysibb.com is going to be dead: https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wysibb.com%2Fforum%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D7%26t%3D2909&edit-text= And WysiBB generated several problems with my non-utf8 website as the js package needs to support utf8. It took me a long time to find out this problem. Now I try sceditor as well.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor and TinyMCE are not jquery plugins, but are easy to integrate with him. Both support bbcode.

Comment: CKEditor 4 is 440kb+. Obviously they're including everything + the kitchen sink and regarding it as required core code. If you want to make text bold/italic/underlined and add lists theres no way it should be anywhere near that size when other plugins claim to do it in 40kb :P